# Setting fitsSystemWindows="true" for Cordova WebView

Tags: android, cordova, webview, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I want to configure Cordova WebView with fitsSystemWindows="true" in order to avoid navbar soft keys overlapping webview content. Ho can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your config.xml

Comment: <preference name="android-fitsSystemWindows" value="true" />